# Excel 2010 Find (dots)-replace(commas)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, find-replace

I am trying to clean data for calculations in excel. The data is taken from a pdf file, and there are numbers where I need to change dots into commas, since if I don't do that, excel understands the "text-to-columns seperated" numbers as dates, and transforms them accordingly which is not what I need.

But after "find-replace"'ing, the data within each cell gets "alt-enter"ed automatically.

I noticed that after a comma, the cell is transformed in this way. For instance, if there are two commas in one cell, then there are two lines in one cell, which creates a problem for me to use text-to-columns to seperate the cells.

So here is the data:

+++

```
Year CPI WPI Year CPI WPI
1960 29.8 31.7 1980 86.3 93.8
1961 30.0 31.6 1981 94.0 98.8
1962 30.4 31.6 1982 97.6 100.5
1963 30.9 31.6 1983 101.3 102.3
1964 31.2 31.7 1984 105.3 103.5
1965 31.8 32.8 1985 109.3 103.6
1966 32.9 33.3 1986 110.5 99.70
1967 33.9 33.7 1987 115.4 104.2
1968 35.5 34.6 1988 120.5 109.0
1969 37.7 36.3 1989 126.1 113.0
1970 39.8 37.1 1990 133.8 118.7
1971 41.1 38.6 1991 137.9 115.9
1972 42.5 41.1 1992 141.9 117.6
1973 46.2 47.4 1993 145.8 118.6
1974 51.9 57.3 1994 149.7 121.9
1975 55.5 59.7 1995 153.5 125.7
1976 58.2 62.5 1996 158.6 128.8
1977 62.1 66.2 1997 161.3 126.7
1978 67.7 72.7 1998 163.9 122.7
1979 76.7 83.4 1999 168.3 128.0
```

+++

I would like to have this data seperated by "space", where the decimals begin with a comma instead with a dot.

Comment: Can't you simply select "space" in the Text to Columns dialog? If I'm reading this right you should end up with 6 columns. I copied your data into a new sheet with no modifications, applied Text to Columns, selected "space" as the delimiter. I ended up with 6 columns of data. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",",")
```

That's exactly what you want isn't it?

[image]